# SharedPreferences in Android AndroidRunTime Exception and NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, exception, sharedpreferences

```
package com.example.cyber.sayac_say;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager; 
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  {

int count;
Button btn;
SharedPreferences ayarlar = null;
RelativeLayout arkaplan;
Boolean ses_durumu, titresim_durumu;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ayarlar = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    ayarlariYukle();




    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    arkaplan = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);




    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            count++;
            btn.setText(""+count);
        }
    });

}
```

hi , this is my codes. And when I used Shared Preferences so I have this error.But when I erase shared preferences lines so error is gone.
The problem is about Shared Prefenrences.I definitely sure.

What can I do before crazy:)?

```
03-22 14:16:23.972 6613-6613/com.example.cyber.sayac_say

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cyber.sayac_say/com.example.cyber.sayac_say.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.example.cyber.sayac_say.MainActivity.ayarlariYukle(MainActivity.java:76)
                                                                           at com.example.cyber.sayac_say.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What are you doing here ayarlariYukle()?  at com.example.cyber.sayac_say.MainActivity.ayarlariYukle(MainActivity.java:76)

Comment: it is a method. But exception is not relevant with this method. Because before ı wrote the method I have this exception.

Comment: if you take a look about the code It's saying that the error It's in the line 76 in the method ayarlariYukle when is called from onCreate line 36.